# php 7 Call to undefined function bcpowmod()

Tags: php, php-7

In the php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcpowmod.php) it say bcpowmod is available in php 5 and 7;
but yet it generates this error when I call it:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bcpowmod() in /var/www/html/m_server/rsa.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/m_server/rsa.php on line 6

my php version is 7.0.27-1;

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $c="86783847632952977412086157561698243841978438961843526495248481240857540800614017742796157091701221586926521683406196232951346965101651654913853333085650688438660428140060738688295363790939030403663113072138797398019359530542546730283500339622261022663247354646694112723768264309805328780089319786037562291192214488451904988111676431033837081606505448192510640474394422008355618865476468661819287488467113947469066064351532882211055722742580973601215238607301587463704999000734946769990548457129880792474396943504719159957419427960698226323851531463715115829962063129967182895698939105651774298278618445630181392903579067705386501503424622616151507384709983459700805448223899164419189070843977815752563863588475502712438119988497573552779469083534213864790618248607122658013913186014816888901510955238307032045204457263801495403569694241566508819927514161696968685050229172515904442772033683417574230783704680046307727919574103050286602783573608426094599232802584618579738973419999663702376236337258483809546700130147658042814237744549458240705821040497452265471167128487575244533495484120735387077042971411156782721610194139107829736852115053243088786223095405479723223823923889351291061604592316562091202826842398663915387437585604";
    $d="801665685888962888197244355884088727439852147080738599384144377429470366654760091829317271547663667107102634963299638571582670062299765457596581625546042480919883485650767793814981364729986819979010079615005445197035974890037933660206855787230268148967152098775913099326932632117226901576219789729374211873007220843565349910138877423270241765020138479950577344773811212067418198839640069663246598599280703915235208352274325047226192694506588063406721922738181096319148695850690404054801931592287128256478741056409246405670444940448497216507609489767759183168247268839949445073864727053124816942818790681169014344867634511901291066937920567017705184687592419928165669322008478022513161848810239449095792208785033427533322872409364729474503472728169548837899230837725517341986214499014590791748486944075718004125384809640974578599454121991026439095574324700306734940564683286827659354516913218016793396021022462783210922894523366494231641356077969171188025542933279442784522396359605530020771666753550799945626747810302259554267490367938977386460492598492541239378947561975189065440744663895679141964801213368229620012875799049950919160679135786728828907973303528749303513248751410937246551512936306242436519867393809170735195284582033";
    $n="1009080091731743571693289351046278241659155498083785303035352630576483682623074792344677256278938918895213486490027434661118838548629426666048998770664368034265094380192339893659056461036168444300779464290105094723584425275005110019762929891439904806953870992537875327288233855319530969319723358035839083538610114708730118254922052965252983416320147803951157904283817950394929253204653540612303467376043089396012173967329974275344043917717479005713639124390046758142896479083599604550753931371023729968594615538237866970545537396039126533212829929914140390798168118502742034759840829272090061229622307933618363099135586969200319913219181083285817169327290144745937229465603077493943760681157087562540069184495178856684045027714672754211224808149519413663928777172520665297244664172704540586803832811952001281301884546420675460138826849834190710429042501652436751608626887733852781993360731407982325048521701074969303881260664281363419196819069525137620435949148247017351815733787896498196082515850943736055788543264778668878829810050965914513308763218840874107308940901471066562672957062596224174989283394676703932588704859675236701065558246056403144925176953413720405014347484111014961975119467666134936765515406687253464906925774503";
    echo bcpowmod($c, $d,$n );
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: It will only be available if compiled with it

Comment: bcmath is an optional module. You'll likely have to `apt-get install php7-bcmath` (or however your OS works) in order to enable it.